# Turning on a transistor if one voltage is higher than another

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, comparator

I would like transistor Q1 to turn on if V1 > V2 with a maximum tolerance of about 0.5 V.

I want to feed the entire circuit with 5 V. Which operational amplifier do you recommend?

And how should the circuit be wired?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbD7Z6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You need to _edit your question_: rephrase it to ask _how to choose a part_ rather than _what part to use_.  Recommendations for specific products are outside of this group's guidelines, partially because today's best recommendation is tomorrow's obsolete part, and partially because there's so many different variables and different parts to choose from that choosing the _very best part_ either requires a long and thorough design study, or an opinion-based decision.

Comment: While you're editing your question -- when you say you want to feed the entire circuit with 5V, do you mean that the power supply voltage available to the amplifier is 0V and +5V?

Comment: Are you aware of how inverting and non-inverting op-amp inputs work? Also, have you considered using a comparator with open-collector output instead an op-amp?

Comment: @TimWescott I've updated the question and hope it's okay now.. I know today's solution won't be the best tomorrow, but I'd like to start making small 5 volt educational circuits out of op-amps and I'd like to avoid having to buy random op-amps .. :)

Comment: Pinguto, you need to state your tolerances because nothing is all that definite within a millivolt of both voltages being equal.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist No.. I'm just starting out and until now I would have tackled the problem with a microcontroller. how can i do this with a comparator?

Comment: @Andyaka Tolerance added.. :)

Comment: OK, you might want to study a bit about comparator hysteresis (it helps to cleanly switch a comparator when both inputs are close). It might be useful to implement it and I mean it might be a useful feature if "variable". Call it a comparator on steroids.

Comment: @Pinguto, In such an open-collector comparator R1 and Q1 are inside.

Comment: You've already fried OA2 (and OA1) by putting -5V on the chip.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks for pointing it out! I corrected the wiring diagram and now it works.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you _really_ want to use a 100 ohm resistor at R1 when you're calling out 35mA at the collector of Q1?  1500 to 3300 ohms would do just fine, and really open up the range of parts you could use.

Comment: Note that if you edit this question so that it isn't asking for a product recommendation, it should get reopened.  Both of the answers you have assume that you did this, so there won't be a need to change them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a comparator (not an op-amp!).  Unless you follow it with an inverting stage (as shown below) you want to connect V1 to the '+' input and V2 to the '-' input.

You want to choose a comparator that will work on your available power supply, and whose common-mode input voltage range *with your chosen power supply voltages* matches V1 and V2.  You want one with a push-pull output that's capable of supplying full base current to the transistor, and can swing close enough to the positive rail to actually supply current.

Your choice of a \$100\Omega\$ resistor and your statement about a 5V supply implies you want 50mA to the base of the transistor -- this is a lot to ask from most comparators, and will severely restrict your choices.  So you may want to boost the current with a PNP-based inverter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNAktf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that R2 and R4 are kind of optional here -- they make sure that Q1 and Q2 (respectively) turn off quickly and reliably.  R4 is *definitely* optional if the comparator you choose has a rail-rail, push-pull output.  If you choose a "superbeta" transistor at Q1 then R1 can be higher yet.  With that \$2.2\mathrm k \Omega\$ resistor at R1 that I called out, you need a comparator that can sink 2mA.

So you need a **comparator** that can:

- Operate off of 0 and 5V
- Has a voltage offset of less than 0.5V (it'd be a poor comparator that couldn't match this).
- Can sink 2mA -- this is moderately low, but you will find parts -- especially ones called "micropower" that can't do this.

---

Your schematic calls out a \$100\Omega\$ base resistor.  This is way way lower than you need for the load you've called out for that transistor (and lower yet if you reduce the current to the LED to be within it's capabilities.

Also, you've chosen an LED that generates 90 mcd of light with 10mA of current.  There are easily-available (in the US and Europe, at least) LEDs that generate **100 times that much light** for the same current.  If you did some shopping and chose a brighter LED there, you could use a higher resistance at (your) R2 and R1, or you could just drive the LED directly from the comparator, probably with less than 1mA of current.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at single supply rail to rail comparators. Comparators are basically opamps that are optimized for comparing voltages.

Comment: Could you recommend me a comparator suitable for my purpose? :)

Comment: **As already mentioned** recommendations for specific parts are outside of this group's guidelines.  We will happily tell you _how_ to choose a part, we will not choose a part for you.

Comment: I would suggest that once you get an answer on how to choose a part you do so, then ask a separate question "Is this part correct?  Why or why not?".  That is within the guidelines (which, by the way, I did not make -- I just refrain from either resisting or subverting them).